# How to select face in edit mode? When I am pressing 2 It's changing the view instead

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode

I know the hotkey is 2 for that but it's changing the view instead of switching to face selection.

Comment: it should be the 2 of the standard keys, not the numpad keys

Comment: ... and it should be 3 not 2 (on the top row of keys, not the numpad) for face selection...

Answer (score 0):

Disable this option in the blender settings to allow use of the number hotkeys as their primary purpose

[image: option]

Note that the <kbd>2</kbd> shortcut is not un the numpad on the right side of the keyboard. It's to the top left, above the <kbd>W</kbd> key.